# Wpf MVVM ComboBox with Checkboxes and Select all Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a ComboBox with CheckBoxes and I would like to implement Select All Option.
I do this in the following way in the XAML:

```
<ComboBox Text="Select Industry"  TextSearch.TextPath ="Industry"  Name="industry"  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem>
                <CheckBox x:Name="allIndustry">All</CheckBox>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource industrySource}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="industry" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=allIndustry, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" Content="{Binding Industry}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I get this functionality in the view using the above code:

[image: All Selected Items ComboBox example]

But, the issue here is that I used to Bind my IsChecked ComboBox property of the ViewModel Property IsChecked , and implementing this solution I lost this feature.

I would like to move the line

```
IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=allIndustry, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Into the

```
<ComboBoxItem>
<CheckBox x:Name="allIndustry">All</CheckBox>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

Change the binding to OneWayToSource, and update from the `x:Name="allIndustry"`
my Selected Items in the CheckBox.

I Should be able to do this only from the XAML View...

After that I would just bind my ComboBox to ViewModel property...

It would look like this:

```
<ComboBox Text="Select Industry"  TextSearch.TextPath ="Industry"  Name="industry"  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem>
                <CheckBox x:Name="allIndustry" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=industry, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWayToSource}">All</CheckBox>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource industrySource}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="industry" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Industry}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

But when I implement this change clicking the Select All does not update my ComboBox Items:

[image: ComboBox Select All fails]

This is the property of the ViewModel

```
 private ObservableCollection<IndustryFilter> _industryFilters;
        public ObservableCollection<IndustryFilter> IndustryFilters
        {
            get { return _industryFilters; }
            set
            {
                _industryFilters = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IndustryFilters"));
            }
        }
```

And this is the Source defined in the upper part of the XAML view

```
<UserControl x:Class="Digital_Data_House_Bulk_Mailer.View.MailView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Digital_Data_House_Bulk_Mailer.View"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Digital_Data_House_Bulk_Mailer.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="industrySource" Source="{Binding IndustryFilters}"/>

    </UserControl.Resources>
```

How to I manage to update All the ComboBoxes named "industry" from the ComboBox.Item Source and keep the "industry" checkbox bound to the ViewModel?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a full working example isn't easy to give a full working example.

You can solve your problem using other approach.

Your `IndustryFilters` shouldn't be an `ObservableCollection<IndustryFilter>` but an instance of an object like this:

```
public class IndustryFilters : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private _isAllChecked;

    public IsAllChecked {
        get {return _isAllChecked;}
        set{
            _isAllChecked = value;

            foreach(var filter in Filters) { 
                filter.IsChecked = value;
            }

            PropertyChanged(...);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IndustryFilter> Filters
    {
        get { return _industryFilters; }
        set
        {
            _industryFilters = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new propertyChangedEventArgs("IndustryFilters"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you bind the `IsChecked` of `<CheckBox x:Name="allIndustry">All</CheckBox>`  to the `IsAllChecked` property.

Then you will have to find a way to change the source of your ComboBox to IndustryFilters.Filters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The update of the Filters works like this but the checkboxes themselves are not updated although I have put <CheckBox Name="industry" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Industry}" />

Comment: I am wondering now why is the CheckBox not updated if I have put the correct binding?

Comment: Does your IndustryFilter implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes, I have resolved this using your idea... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of bruno.almeida I have managed to solve this

This is the ViewModel property definition for the State filter - same as the Industry field i asked:

```
private ObservableCollection<StateFilter> _stateFilters;
        public ObservableCollection<StateFilter> StateFilters
        {
            get { return _stateFilters; }
            set
            {
                _stateFilters = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StateFilters"));
            }
        }

        private bool _stateFilter;
        public bool StateFilter
        {
            get { return _stateFilter; }
            set
            {
                _stateFilter = value;

                ObservableCollection<StateFilter> local = new ObservableCollection<StateFilter>();

                foreach (var filter in StateFilters)
                {
                    filter.IsChecked = _stateFilter;
                    local.Add(filter);

                }
                StateFilters = local;

                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StateFilter"));

            }
        }
```

This is the XAML code example:

Resources:

ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Text="Select State"  TextSearch.TextPath ="State"  Name="state"  IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" >

    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem >
                <CheckBox  Name="all" IsChecked="{Binding StateFilter}">All</CheckBox>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource stateSource}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="chkTask" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"  Content="{Binding State}" ></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: If your StateFilter implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you don't need the local variable.

Comment: Yes I do have INotifyPropertyChanged, but the catch looks that my setter on the ObervableList was not getting set when I was only changing the property IsChecked of the object in the list... I thought that I was maybe to override the Equals method but ... I saw I was already getting the results since I am new to WPF - for such a trivial task (I am more into web development) this Select All feature is a pain ...

Comment: Previous to introducing local variable a was using this :
                foreach (var filter in StateFilters)
                {
                    StateFilters .IsChecked = _stateFilter;
                    

                } , but the setter was not getting called

Comment: You misunderstand. You have ObservableCollection<StateFilter>. ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged. But, based on your description looks like the StateFilter object himself does not implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is a plain EntityFramework class derived from db object